# Sort 'Days' Items in Sitecore according to days of week

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

Is there any way to sort the following items according to the days of week.

[image]

In C# I can do something like this:

```
string [] initialArray = {"Friday", "Monday", ... } ; 

string [] sortedArray = initialArray.OrderBy(s => Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), s)).ToArray() ;
```

But I don't know how can I achieve this kind of functionality with Sitecore.

Comment: What is your intention, exactly? Would you like these items to be automatically sorted inside of the folder in the Content Editor? Or?..

Comment: Why not set the Sortorder Field in Sitecore.?

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko When I get the items and show on the page. They appear in the same order as shown in picture in my question. I am thinking to sort them in Sitecore. So that when I get them they are already sorted.

Comment: @JanBluemink I don't have any idea about Sortorder Field I will google it now. Thanks!

Comment: `They appear in the same order as shown in picture` - Why don't you just, you know, sort them manually? Click+Drag them, or move them up/down from the Home tab on Ribbon

Comment: @jammykam No, there are many departments and each branch has its own "Opening Hours" Folder. Then I have to do Manually for all of them and for each new Department I have to do it manually every time.

Comment: You'll have to create your own sorter then, or use Branch templates to create a pre-sorted set of items.

Comment: @jammykam Well these Items with Days names are created with Branch Items. In the Branches I have sorted the Items. But once they are created inside the Department. They again get sorted by name.  It would be nice of you, if in few sentences you can write how I can implement my own sorter. Thanks !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you really care is to display the days sorted on the front-end regardless of how they are organised in the Content Editor then simply sort them in code before you display them, e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

var openingHours = Sitecore.Context.Item.Children
                           .OrderBy(s => Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), s.DisplayName));
```

If you want to sort them in the Content Editor then you need to create a custom sorter. Sitecore Climber has provided links, but for this specific example you can use:

```
using Sitecore.Data.Comparers;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;

public class DayOfWeekComparer : Comparer
{
    protected override int DoCompare(Item item1, Item item2)
    {
        var x = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), item1.DisplayName);
        var y = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), item2.DisplayName);
        return x.CompareTo(y);
    }
}
```

Then in the `core` database create an item of item type `/sitecore/templates/System/Child Sorting` under `/sitecore/system/Settings/Subitems Sorting` and set the type to your class.

You should set the Subitem Sorting on the Standard values of a template. In this instance it looks like you have a simple Folder template, so you would need to create a more specific template for your Opening Hours folder. Even so, the user can still decide to re-order the items OR change the default sort for that folder. The only guaranteed way to force the output is by sorting before you render, i.e. the first bit of code.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Forcing the output by sorting before rendering is more reliable option.

Answer (score 0):

please check next articles:

http://firebreaksice.com/how-to-sort-sitecore-items-in-the-content-editor/

http://sitecore.alexiasoft.nl/2009/08/04/sorting-sitecore-items/

http://sitecoreblog.blogspot.in/2010/11/change-default-subitems-sort-order.html